# If I drop a PG table with an index, does the index still exist?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

If I'm dropping and re-creating a Postgres table that is indexed, will the index still exist?

Do I need to drop and re-index the table after re-creating it or do I just need to re-create the index on the new table and leave the cleaning up of the old index to Postgres?

Comment: Why didn't you try it out? The index gets dropped when the table is dropped. Automatically generated indexes (e.g. primary key, unique) will be re-created when the table is re-created, manually created indexes won't. You cannot have an index without an associated table.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Drop table will delete all related constraints, & index, no need for you to do any kind of cleanup. Postgres will handle that.